# How to add a new property to an existing prototype/construction function along with its parameter

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype

this is for educational purposes only, say I have an existing prototype/ constructor function:

```
var Dog = function(name, age, color){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.color = color;
};

var pitBull = new Dog('Rocky', 5, 'black');
```

that I want to add  (via coding) a new parameter called `type` to it like this:

```
    var Dog = function(name, age, color, type){
    // code goes here.. };
```

and at the same time I want to add a new property with the exact name like so:

```
    this.type = type;
```

so I can do this:

```
    var pitBull = new Dog('Rocky', 5, 'black', 'PitBull');
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's clarify that a prototype is not the same thing as a constructor. What you are showing is a constructor function. This function will be used to construct new objects that conform to the interface that you create, but it will also inherit properties from an underlying object - - that object is the prototype.

```
// This is your constructor function that takes arguments that help
// it construct the instance properties:
var Dog = function(name, age, color){
  // These are the instance properties
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.color = color;
};

// And, here you are constructing a new instance of Dog
var pitBull = new Dog('Rocky', 5, 'black');
```

*"I want to add (via coding) a new parameter called type to it like this"*

```
var Dog = function(name, age, color, type){
// code goes here.. };
```

Changing the constructor's basic parameter structure after it's been made really isn't the right approach. What you should do is create a new sub-type with a new constructor function and have the new type inherit from the old type. The new type will take all 4 parameters, but it will only set the newest one and it will pass the other 3 down to the underlying object that it is inheriting from.

*"and at the same time I want to add a new property with the exact name"*

No problem:

```
// Make new constructor function
function BetterDog(name, age, color, type){
  this.type = type;  // New property based on new parameter value

  // Now pass the original 3 parameters to the prototype
  // and let that object will handle the arguments as normal
  Dog.prototype.constructor.call(this, name, age, color);
}

// Now, we'll set this new object to inherit from the earlier one by setting
// it's prototype to a new instance of a Dog. A new BetterDog is now going
// to inherit all the properties of Dog
BetterDog.prototype = new Dog();

// But, one problem here is that when we try to make a new instance of 
// BetterDog, the Dog constructor function will be called. This happens
// because we switched the prototype. We can fix that like this:
BetterDog.constructor = BetterDog;

// Finally, we can construct a new BetterDog with all 4 parameters:
var pitBull = new BetterDog('Rocky', 5, 'black', 'PitBull');
```

The whole thing together:

```js
    // This is your constructor function that takes arguments that help
    // it construct the instance properties:
    var Dog = function(name, age, color){
      // These are the instance properties
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.color = color;
    };

    // Make new constructor function
    function BetterDog(name, age, color, type){
      this.type = type;
 
      // Now pass the original 3 parameters to the prototype
      // and let that object will handle the arguments as normal
      Dog.prototype.constructor.call(this, name, age, color);
    }

    // Now, we'll set this new object to inherit from the earlier one by setting
    // it's prototype to a new instance of a Dog. A new BetterDog is now going
    // to inherit all the properties of Dog
    BetterDog.prototype = new Dog();

    // But, one problem here is that when we try to make a new instance of 
    // BetterDog, the Dog constructor function will be called. This happens
    // because we switched the prototype. We can fix that like this:
    BetterDog.constructor = BetterDog;

    // Finally, we can construct a new BetterDog with all 4 parameters:
    var pitBull = new BetterDog('Rocky', 5, 'black', 'PitBull');

    // Test:
    console.log(pitBull.name);
    console.log(pitBull.age);
    console.log(pitBull.color);
    console.log(pitBull.type);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but let's just say for the sake of argument that I want to change the "constructor's basic parameter structure after it's been made" even if it's not the correct way to do it, how do I do that?

Comment: @kapreski In that case, you would have to redefine the function (as if it never existed in the first place).

Comment: @kapreski You do know that all arguments are optional in JavaScript, right? You could set up the original constructor will all 4 parameters, but only call it with 3 of them if you like. If you did this, you'd just have to test the parameter value(s) for `undefined` before setting properties based on them.